# valueupdate enables dirtyflag in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

This is my html

```
<textarea id="emp" data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', restrictnumberofwords : 50,  event: { keydown: test}" ></textarea>
```

this is knockout code

```
ko.bindingHandlers.restrictnumberofwords = {
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel)
{

   element.value = element.value.substr(0, valueAccessor());
   allBindingsAccessor().value(element.value.substr(0, valueAccessor()));
}
};

function test(data, e) {

    //some logic which will restrict user to type specific number of characters
}
```

In my actual code i have autosave fuctionality which will make dirtyflag true whenever we type something in textarea. But i dont want to enable dirtyflag everytime user types in textarea. it should only enable autosave if we tab out from control. How to acheive it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `textInput` binding for live updates, and the `value` binding for updates on blur:

```js
const liveInput = ko.observable("");
const slowInput = ko.observable("");
const charCount = ko.pureComputed(() => liveInput().length);

ko.applyBindings({ liveInput, slowInput, charCount });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="textInput: liveInput, value: slowInput" placeholder="type to see two values sync">


<p>Live: <span data-bind="text: liveInput"></span></p>
<p>On blur: <span data-bind="text: slowInput"></span></p>
<p>Char. count: <span data-bind="text: charCount"></span></p>
```

Comment: but i need to use valueUpdate because it instantly tells me how many characters i have typed

Comment: You can track the character count by subscribing to `liveInput`. I'll add an example.

Comment: if i dont use valueUpdate then it doesnt update number of characters count.

Comment: see this with computed 
http://jsfiddle.net/kirannandedkar/LkqTU/63413/

Comment: So you want to ensure (1) The output has a maximum of 6 lines, and (2) each line has a maxium of 42 characters?

Comment: i achieve all that but its only due to valueUpdate my autosave gets enabled on every character i type and that i dont want

Comment: Maybe you can use the `blur` event instead of the `keydown`? Like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/8jcayL6m/

Comment: strangely in my code value of character count only updates after it looses focus.. although computed observable changes whenever i type something but i cant see till i tab out of control. what can be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, I think you need to remove value update.

```
<textarea id="emp" data-bind="value: lastName,  restrictnumberofwords : 50,  event: { keydown: test}" ></textarea>
```

Comment: but i need to use valueUpdate because it instantly tells me how many characters i have typed